# Strange visualization for H2S element

Tags: acegen

I am experiencing a strange behavior in the postprocessing of H2S element. I have provided a MWE below.

Reference: H2 element

```
<< AceFEM`;


{Ro, Ri, L} = {5., 4., 10.};
{N1, N2, N3} = 2 {1, 28, 10};

ez = {0, 0, -1};
S3 = {{{Ri, 0, 0}, {Ro, 0, 0}}, {{Ri, 0, L}, {Ro, 0, L}}};
n\[Alpha] = 200;

sections = 
  Table[ Map[RotationMatrix[\[Alpha], ez] . # &, S3, {2}], {\[Alpha], 0, 
    2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/n\[Alpha]} ];

SMTInputData[]; SMTAddDomain[{"A", "OL:SED3H2DFHYH2NeoHooke", {}}];
SMTAddMesh[Raster3D[sections], "A", "H2", {N1, N3, N2}];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[{
   {"Z" == 0 &, 3 -> 0}, {"Z" == L &, 3 -> 5},
   {"Z" == 0 &, 1 -> 0, 2 -> 0}
   }];
SMTAnalysis["Output" -> "H2test.out"];

SMTNextStep[0.1, 0.1];

While[
  While[
   step = SMTConvergence[10^-10, 15, {"Adaptive Time", 7, 0.01, 0.1, 1}], 
   SMTNewtonIteration[];];
  If[step[[4]] === "MinBound", 
   SMTStatusReport["\[CapitalDelta]\[Lambda] < \[CapitalDelta]\[Lambda]min"];];
  step[[3]] 
  , If[step[[1]], SMTStepBack[];];
  SMTNextStep[step[[2]], step[[2]]]
  ];

SMTShowMesh["DeformedMesh" -> True, "Field" -> "Ezz"]
```

The visualization here is obtained as expected.

[image]

Now: H2S element

```
<< AceFEM`;

{Ro, Ri, L} = {5., 4., 10.};
{N1, N2, N3} = 2 {1, 28, 10};

ez = {0, 0, -1};
S3 = {{{Ri, 0, 0}, {Ro, 0, 0}}, {{Ri, 0, L}, {Ro, 0, L}}};
n\[Alpha] = 200;

sections = 
  Table[ Map[RotationMatrix[\[Alpha], ez] . # &, S3, {2}], {\[Alpha], 
    0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/n\[Alpha]} ];

SMTInputData[]; SMTAddDomain[{"A", "OL:SED3H2SDFHYH2SNeoHooke", {}}];
SMTAddMesh[Raster3D[sections], "A", "H2S", {N1, N3, N2}];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[{
   {"Z" == 0 &, 3 -> 0}, {"Z" == L &, 3 -> 5},
   {"Z" == 0 &, 1 -> 0, 2 -> 0}
   }];
SMTAnalysis["Output" -> "H2Stest.out"];

SMTNextStep[0.1, 0.1];

While[
  While[
   step = 
    SMTConvergence[10^-10, 15, {"Adaptive Time", 7, 0.01, 0.1, 1}], 
   SMTNewtonIteration[];];
  If[step[[4]] === "MinBound", 
   SMTStatusReport[
     "\[CapitalDelta]\[Lambda] < \[CapitalDelta]\[Lambda]min"];];
  step[[3]] 
  , If[step[[1]], SMTStepBack[];];
  SMTNextStep[step[[2]], step[[2]]]
  ];

SMTShowMesh["DeformedMesh" -> True, "Field" -> "Ezz"]
```

But the visualization here results in

[image]

As you can see, a strange checkerboard appears. Any idea what is happening?

I am using Mathematica V13 and AceGen/AceFEM V7.504.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a bug in Mathematica 13.0 polygon rendering procedures. Simple example does not work either. Good news is that the bug was removed in new Mathematica 13.1. Thus, upgrade your Mathematica.

[image: Simple example rendered in MMA 13]

[image: Simple example rendered in MMA 12.3]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the problem but on my system: Win10, Mathematica V12.1 and AceGen/AceFEM V7.501 and V7.504 I got correct plot.

Comment: Thanks but I have Mathematica 13.